# VGA screen DVI - D , DVI - A or HDMI adapter?

Tags: display, vga, dvi, display-adapter

I've got an old lcd vga monitor and I would like to connect it on my Asus Prime 450 motherboard via one of the digital ports in order to experiment with my Radeon Graphic Vega 8 graphic card's scaling, custom resolution and aspect ratio capabilities. They are not available through the VGA port. Only through DVI D or HDMI

THESE ARE THE SPECS

Integrated Graphics in the 2nd and 1st Gen AMD Ryzen™ with Radeon™ Vega Graphics/ Athlon™ with Radeon™ Vega Graphics Processors
Multi-VGA output support : HDMI/DVI-D/D-Sub ports
Supports HDMI 2.0b with maximum resolution of 4096 x 2160 @ 60 Hz
Supports DVI-D with max. resolution 1920 x 1200 @ 60 Hz
Supports D-sub with max. resolution 1920 x 1200 @ 60 Hz

What kind of adapter do I need in order to do so? VGA female to DVI - A male , to DVI - D or to HDMI ? Active or passive? Converter or adapter? Pretty confusing I guess. Could you provide any example with link please?

Thanks

Comment: "They are not available through the VGA" at either end. VGA has limited capabilities. What do you hope to achieve by using a HDMI to VGA adapter? You're constrained by the VGA monitor.

Comment: As I mentioned on the original post I would like to  experiment with my Radeon Graphic Vega 8 graphic card's scaling, custom resolution and aspect ratio capabilities

Comment: VGA accepts analog signals only.  Passive adapters cannot change a digital signal (DVI-D or HDMI) to analog. DVI-I or DVI-A are the only DVI ports that can output analog directly.  If you used an [active converter](https://www.amazon.com/Active-DVI-D-Adapter-Benfei-Female/dp/B07D3XZ9SD/) to convert digital to analog, you'll also be constrained by the accepted input resolutions of the converter, as well as the resolutions accepted by the VGA monitor. You're unlikely to get any different resolution capabilities than connecting the D-SUB directly to the monitor with a VGA cable.